# R merge horizontally on duplicates

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes and have multiple matches append horizontally:

dataset1:

```
id
1 email1
1 email1b
2 email2
3 email3
```

dataset2:

```
id name
1 bob
2 rob
3 kat
```

I would like to use merge to combine these dataframes on id. When there are duplicate matches with id 1, I would like merge by "id" to return both results horizontally:

```
id name email 
1 bob email1 email1b
2 rob email2
3 kat email3
```

It doesn't seem like merge can do this, it creates multiple rows for duplicate values. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate dataset1 beforehand like this:

```
dataset1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id email
1 email1
1 email1b
2 email2
3 email3")

dataset2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id name
1 bob
2 rob
3 kat")

dataset1 <- with(dataset1, aggregate(x = email, by = list(id = id), FUN = paste, collapse = " "))
merge(x = dataset1, y = dataset2, by = "id")[, c(1, 3, 2)]
#   id name              x
# 1  1  bob email1 email1b
# 2  2  rob         email2
# 3  3  kat         email3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset1 <- aggregate(email ~ id, dataset1, paste, collapse = " ")
merge(dataset2, dataset1, by = "id")

#   id name           email
# 1  1  bob email1  email1b
# 2  2  rob          email2
# 3  3  kat          email3
```

---

If you into some fun with fast aggregations and merges for big data sets, here's `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setkey(dataset1 <- setDT(dataset1)[, list(email = paste(email, collapse = " ")), by = id], id)
setkey(setDT(dataset2), id)
dataset2[dataset1]

##    id name          email
## 1:  1  bob email1 email1b
## 2:  2  rob         email2
## 3:  3  kat         email3
```

Comment: You need to add `collapse=" "` to your first example too, like: `aggregate(email ~ id, data=merge(dataset1,dataset2,by="id"), FUN=function(x) paste(x,collapse=" ") )`

Comment: @thelatemail, I'm well aware of the `paste` functionality. I just think this code looks nice and clean and I assumed it wouldn't matter for the OP if there is a comma or a space there. If it does, it will encourage him to try `data.table` (which is where I was manily aiming to)

Comment: There is no comma in the aggregate result you have in the first example. That is the problem. Try `aggregate(email ~ id, dataset1, paste)$email[1]` - it is a list instead of a vector. The comma is just produced with the `print` method.